a fortnight ago = a fortnight ago today?
This is a question about British English.
(1) I met her a fortnight ago.
(2) I met her a fortnight ago today.
Do these two sentences have the same meaning?
In Japanese, I met her a fortnight ago probably means "I met her about a fortnight ago", hence this question.

I wouldn't say that (1) probably means 'about a fortnight', but it could have that meaning. Adding 'today' emphasises that it was exactly 14 days ago.

Sometimes there is a good reason to add "today" to a statement about a time period. This is because time periods like "a week" or "a month" are ambiguous. For example, a week can mean a calendar week (ie Sunday to the following Saturday, or Monday to Sunday in other contexts), or any 7 day period. Likewise, a month can be a calendar month of varying length, a lunar month marked by the phases of the moon, or any 28 day period. So, saying "a week today" on a Wednesday, for example, would mean a time period measured from the previous Wednesday until now, or from the current day to the following Wednesday.
This means that if someone said, for example, "I'm starting my new job in a week" that may not mean in exactly 7 days - I would assume they meant at the start of the next calendar week because most working weeks are measured on the calendar.
A 'fortnight' is not a time period measured on the calendar. It means 'fourteen nights'. So, that ambiguity isn't there. I'd say there is no need to say "a fortnight ago today", but on the other hand it isn't grammatically incorrect and it does make it very clear.
